# xslt is printing all tag from xml unnecessarily

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt

i am trying to print some specific xml tag in an xslt pdf. But when i tried to print the selected tags every thing went worse. every filed is showing all the tags from 1st to last in every printed field.

```
<BrokerSysteM>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:data="http://vedaadvantage.com/data" xmlns:v="http://vedaadvantage.com/v_ppsr-v0-1-0.xsd" xmlns:veda="http://vedaadvantage.com/veda-ppsr-v0-1-0.xsd">
  <soap:Header />
  <soap:Body>
    <v:registrationNumberSearchResponse>
      <data:SearchByRegistrationNumberResponseType>
        <data:CustomersRequestMessageId>?</data:CustomersRequestMessageId>
        <data:CustomersUserDefinedFields>
          <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
          <data:CustomersUserDefinedField>
            <data:FieldName>?</data:FieldName>
            <data:FieldValue>?</data:FieldValue>
          </data:CustomersUserDefinedField>
        </data:CustomersUserDefinedFields>
        <data:PpsrRequestMessageId>?</data:PpsrRequestMessageId>
        <data:RequestProcessedByEnvironment>?</data:RequestProcessedByEnvironment>
        <data:RequestProcessedDateTime>?</data:RequestProcessedDateTime>
        <data:PpsrTransactionId>?</data:PpsrTransactionId>
        <data:SearchCriteria>
          <data:RegistrationNumber>?</data:RegistrationNumber>
        </data:SearchCriteria>
        <data:SearchResult>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <data:ResultDetail>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <data:ChangeHistory>
              <data:ChangeDetails>
                <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                <data:ChangeDetail>
                  <data:ChangeNumber>?</data:ChangeNumber>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:ChangeType>?</data:ChangeType>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:RegistrationChangeTime>?</data:RegistrationChangeTime>
                </data:ChangeDetail>
              </data:ChangeDetails>
            </data:ChangeHistory>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <data:RegistrationDetail>
              <data:AddressForService>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <data:Addressee>?</data:Addressee>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <data:EmailAddress>?</data:EmailAddress>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <data:FaxNumber>?</data:FaxNumber>
                <data:MailingAddress>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:CountryName>?</data:CountryName>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:ISO3166CountryCode>?</data:ISO3166CountryCode>
                  <data:Line1>?</data:Line1>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Line2>?</data:Line2>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Line3>?</data:Line3>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Locality>?</data:Locality>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Postcode>?</data:Postcode>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:State>?</data:State>
                </data:MailingAddress>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <data:PhysicalAddress>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:CountryName>?</data:CountryName>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:ISO3166CountryCode>?</data:ISO3166CountryCode>
                  <data:Line1>?</data:Line1>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Line2>?</data:Line2>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Line3>?</data:Line3>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Locality>?</data:Locality>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Postcode>?</data:Postcode>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:State>?</data:State>
                </data:PhysicalAddress>
              </data:AddressForService>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:AreAssetsSubjectToControl>?</data:AreAssetsSubjectToControl>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:AreProceedsClaimed>?</data:AreProceedsClaimed>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:Attachments>
                <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                <data:AttachmentDetail>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:AttachmentDescription>?</data:AttachmentDescription>
                  <data:AttachmentFileName>?</data:AttachmentFileName>
                  <data:AttachmentFileSizeBytes>?</data:AttachmentFileSizeBytes>
                  <data:AttachmentId>?</data:AttachmentId>
                  <data:IsMigratedAttachment>?</data:IsMigratedAttachment>
                </data:AttachmentDetail>
              </data:Attachments>
              <data:ChangeNumber>?</data:ChangeNumber>
              <data:CollateralClassDescription>?</data:CollateralClassDescription>
              <data:CollateralClassType>?</data:CollateralClassType>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:CollateralDescription>?</data:CollateralDescription>
              <data:CollateralType>?</data:CollateralType>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:EarlierRegistrationNumber>?</data:EarlierRegistrationNumber>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:GivingOfNoticeIdentifier>?</data:GivingOfNoticeIdentifier>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:Grantors>
                <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                <data:GrantorSearchDetail>
                  <data:GrantorType>?</data:GrantorType>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Individual>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <data:FamilyName>?</data:FamilyName>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <data:GivenNames>?</data:GivenNames>
                  </data:Individual>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Organisation>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <data:OrganisationName>?</data:OrganisationName>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <data:OrganisationNumber>?</data:OrganisationNumber>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <data:OrganisationNumberType>?</data:OrganisationNumberType>
                  </data:Organisation>
                </data:GrantorSearchDetail>
              </data:Grantors>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:IsInventory>?</data:IsInventory>
              <data:IsMigrated>?</data:IsMigrated>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:IsPMSI>?</data:IsPMSI>
              <data:IsSecurityInterestRegistrationKind>?</data:IsSecurityInterestRegistrationKind>
              <data:IsSubordinate>?</data:IsSubordinate>
              <data:IsTransitional>?</data:IsTransitional>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:MigrationDetail>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <data:OriginalStartDate>?</data:OriginalStartDate>
                <data:SourceRegister>?</data:SourceRegister>
              </data:MigrationDetail>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:ProceedsClaimedDescription>?</data:ProceedsClaimedDescription>
              <data:RegistrationChangeTime>?</data:RegistrationChangeTime>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:RegistrationEndTime>?</data:RegistrationEndTime>
              <data:RegistrationKind>?</data:RegistrationKind>
              <data:RegistrationNumber>?</data:RegistrationNumber>
              <data:RegistrationStartTime>?</data:RegistrationStartTime>
              <data:SecuredParties>
                <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                <data:CollateralRegistrationSecuredParty>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Individual>
                    <data:FamilyName>?</data:FamilyName>
                    <data:GivenNames>?</data:GivenNames>
                  </data:Individual>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:Organisation>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <data:OrganisationName>?</data:OrganisationName>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <data:OrganisationNumber>?</data:OrganisationNumber>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <data:OrganisationNumberType>?</data:OrganisationNumberType>
                  </data:Organisation>
                  <data:SecuredPartyType>?</data:SecuredPartyType>
                </data:CollateralRegistrationSecuredParty>
              </data:SecuredParties>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:SerialNumberDetails>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <data:AdditionalAircraftDetails>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:AircraftNationality>?</data:AircraftNationality>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:AircraftNationalityCodeAndRegistrationMark>?</data:AircraftNationalityCodeAndRegistrationMark>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:ManufacturersModel>?</data:ManufacturersModel>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:ManufacturersName>?</data:ManufacturersName>
                </data:AdditionalAircraftDetails>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <data:AdditionalVehicleDetails>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:VehicleDescriptiveText>?</data:VehicleDescriptiveText>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:VehicleRegistrationNumber>?</data:VehicleRegistrationNumber>
                </data:AdditionalVehicleDetails>
                <data:SerialNumber>?</data:SerialNumber>
                <data:SerialNumberType>?</data:SerialNumberType>
              </data:SerialNumberDetails>
            </data:RegistrationDetail>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <data:RestrictionDetail>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:IsAccessRestricted>?</data:IsAccessRestricted>
              <data:IsArchived>?</data:IsArchived>
              <data:IsRemoved>?</data:IsRemoved>
              <data:RegistrationNumber>?</data:RegistrationNumber>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:RemovalDetail>
                <data:RemovalReasonDescription>?</data:RemovalReasonDescription>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <data:RemovalReasonFurtherDetails>?</data:RemovalReasonFurtherDetails>
              </data:RemovalDetail>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <data:RestrictedAccessDetail>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <data:RegistrationEndTime>?</data:RegistrationEndTime>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <data:RestrictedAccessReasonDescription>?</data:RestrictedAccessReasonDescription>
              </data:RestrictedAccessDetail>
            </data:RestrictionDetail>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <data:ResultSequenceNumber>?</data:ResultSequenceNumber>
          </data:ResultDetail>
          <data:SearchResultRetrievedDateTime>?</data:SearchResultRetrievedDateTime>
        </data:SearchResult>
        <data:SearchSummary>
          <data:AccessToSearchResultExpiryTime>?</data:AccessToSearchResultExpiryTime>
          <data:ResultCount>?</data:ResultCount>
          <data:SearchExecutedDateTime>?</data:SearchExecutedDateTime>
          <data:SearchNumber>?</data:SearchNumber>
          <data:SearchType>?</data:SearchType>
        </data:SearchSummary>
      </data:SearchByRegistrationNumberResponseType>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <veda:certificateUnavailableWarningMessage>?</veda:certificateUnavailableWarningMessage>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <veda:searchCertificateNumber>?</veda:searchCertificateNumber>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <data:RetrieveSearchCertificateResponseType>
        <data:CustomersRequestMessageId>?</data:CustomersRequestMessageId>
        <data:CustomersUserDefinedFields>
          <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
          <data:CustomersUserDefinedField>
            <data:FieldName>?</data:FieldName>
            <data:FieldValue>?</data:FieldValue>
          </data:CustomersUserDefinedField>
        </data:CustomersUserDefinedFields>
        <data:PpsrRequestMessageId>?</data:PpsrRequestMessageId>
        <data:RequestProcessedByEnvironment>?</data:RequestProcessedByEnvironment>
        <data:RequestProcessedDateTime>?</data:RequestProcessedDateTime>
        <data:AccessToSearchCertificateExpiryTime>?</data:AccessToSearchCertificateExpiryTime>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <data:Attachments>
          <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
          <data:AttachmentDetail>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <data:AttachmentDescription>?</data:AttachmentDescription>
            <data:AttachmentFileName>?</data:AttachmentFileName>
            <data:AttachmentFileSizeBytes>?</data:AttachmentFileSizeBytes>
            <data:AttachmentId>?</data:AttachmentId>
            <data:IsMigratedAttachment>?</data:IsMigratedAttachment>
          </data:AttachmentDetail>
        </data:Attachments>
        <data:PpsrTransactionId>?</data:PpsrTransactionId>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <data:SearchCertificateCreatedDateTime>?</data:SearchCertificateCreatedDateTime>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <data:SearchCertificateFile>cid:1334450805058</data:SearchCertificateFile>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <data:SearchCertificateFileName>?</data:SearchCertificateFileName>
        <data:SearchCertificateNumber>?</data:SearchCertificateNumber>
      </data:RetrieveSearchCertificateResponseType>
    </v:registrationNumberSearchResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
</BrokerSysteM>
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:ibex="http://www.xmlpdf.com/2003/ibex/Format" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="BrokerSysteM">
        <root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <layout-master-set>
                <simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-width="8.27in" page-height="11.69in" margin="1cm">
                    <region-body region-name="Pages"
                    margin-top="0cm" 
                    margin-bottom="0.5cm" 
                    margin-left="0.1cm" 
                    margin-right="0.1cm" 
                    text-align="justify"
                    font-size="7pt" 
                    />
                    <region-before extent="0.5cm" region-name="header"/>
                    <region-after extent="2cm" region-name="footer"/>
                </simple-page-master>
            </layout-master-set>
            <page-sequence master-reference="simple">
            <static-content flow-name="header">
                <block padding-bottom="5pt"></block>
            </static-content>
            <!-- Header End -->




        <flow flow-name="Pages">
            <block text-align="center" ><external-graphic text-align="left" display-align="left" src="url(\var\copl\exclude\docs\broker\logo.jpg)"/></block>
            <block text-align="center" margin-bottom="5pt">Australian Credit Licence Number 383999 </block>
            <block font-size="10pt" text-align="center" margin-top="10pt" font-weight="bold">Registration Number Search</block>
            <block margin-left="25pt" margin-right="25pt" margin-top="5pt">
                <table border="0.5pt solid black">
                    <table-column column-width="35%" column-number="1"/>
                    <table-column column-width="65%" column-number="2"/>
                    <table-body>
                        <table-row background-color="#c7c7c7">
                            <table-cell number-columns-spanned="6">
                                <block font-weight="bold" text-align="left" margin-left="5pt" margin-top="1pt" margin-bottom="1pt"> Registration Number Search</block>  
                            </table-cell>
                        </table-row>
                        <table-row border-top="0.5pt solid black" >
                            <table-cell border-right="0.5pt solid black" >
                                <block text-align="left" margin-left="5pt" margin-top="1pt" margin-bottom="1pt" >
                                Customer Request Message ID:
                                </block>    
                            </table-cell>
                            <table-cell border-right="0.5pt solid black" >
                                <block text-align="left" margin-left="5pt" margin-top="1pt" margin-bottom="1pt"  >
                                <xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/v:retrieveRegistrationAttachmentResponse/data:RetrieveRegistrationAttachmentResponseType/data:CustomersRequestMessageId" />
                                </block>    
                            </table-cell>
                        </table-row>
                    </table-body>
                </table>
            </block>
        <block break-after="page"/> 
    </flow>
    <static-content flow-name="footer">
    <block font-size="6pt">
        <table>
        <table-column column-width="50%"  column-number="1" />
        <table-column column-width="50%" column-number="2" />
            <table-body>
                <table-row  color="gray" line-height="16pt">
                    <table-cell text-align="left" >
                        <block font-size="7pt" margin-top="5px">&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0; Generated: <xsl:value-of select="TimeStamp/Date"/>&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0; at: <xsl:value-of select="TimeStamp/Time"/> &#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;By:  <xsl:value-of select="GeneratedBy"/></block>
                    </table-cell> 
                    <table-cell font-size="6pt" text-align="right">
                        <block text-align="right">Page:<fo:page-number/></block>
                    </table-cell> 
                </table-row>
            </table-body>
        </table>                                
    </block>
    </static-content>
    </page-sequence>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the mechanism(which utility software) use to print pdf from (xml & xslt).

Comment: i am using ibex pdf generator . i have to input xslt and xml file in ibex and it generates output in the form of PDF. the xml and xsl code i have attached in the question. and PDF generator is also printing the document with no error, but it is repeating all the tags in every field of PDF.

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/v:retrieveRegistrationAttachmentResponse/data:RetrieveRegistrationAttachmentResponseType/data:CustomersRequestMessageId" /> where have you define the soap : envelope namespace??

Comment: i have defined this name space in xml and in xsl where the tag value is to be called. in xsl the same line you sent only this line   is using this name space , but the namespace is defined in xml.

Comment: You have to add namespaces in xsl as well, which are using in your xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining your code of both files i found that the  following
section is missing from the header part of the xsl   Please use the
same namespaces in xslt  declared in xml:

```
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  
xmlns:v="http://vedaadvantage.com/v_ppsr-v0-1-0.xsd"  
xmlns:veda="http://vedaadvantage.com/veda-ppsr-v0-1-0.xsd"  
xmlns:data="http://vedaadvantage.com/data"
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in template rule in XSLT processes all elements for which you haven't defined a more specific rule. The effect of the built-in rule is to output the contained text. If you want different behaviour for unmatched elements the simplest approach is to add the rule

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```